# How to use a repository object inside a function in a ViewModel class Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I have this class:

```
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(repository: MyRepository): ViewModel () {
    lateinit var myLiveData: LiveData<User>

    fun signIn(credential: AuthCredential) {
        myLiveData = repository.signIn(credential)
    }

    val otherLiveData = repository.signOut() //Works fine
}
```

The problem is that the `repository` cannot be used inside the signIn function and I don't know why. However, the second call to signOut works. Can anyone please help?

Comment: add val to the constructor parameter to make it available to the whole class.
`val repository: MyRepository`

Comment: @RaviKumar So simple. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a class with primary constructor and parameter like this:

```
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(repository: MyRepository): ViewModel () { ... }
```

leads to the fact that `repository` parameter is not a **property**, which means it can't be used in other functions of the class. But it can be used in the initializer blocks and in property initializers declared in the class body:

```
class MyViewModel(repo: MyRepository) {
    val repository = repo
}
```

However, Kotlin has more concise syntax for declaring properties and initializing them from the primary constructor, using `val` or `var` keyword:

```
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(val repository: MyRepository): ViewModel () { ... }
```

If you declare parameter with `val` or `var` keyword it will be treated as a property and be available in other functions of the class.

[More info about constructors and parameters in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors).

Comment: Thank you for the complete explanation.